# Python3 How to get raw bytes string without encode?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get a string of origin bytes (assemble code) without encoding to another encoding. As the content of bytes is shellcode, I do not need to encode it and want to write it directly as raw bytes.
By simplify, I want to convert "b'\xb7\x00\x00\x00'" to "\xb7\x00\x00\x00" and get the string representation of raw bytes.
For example:

```
>> byte_code = b'\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>> uc_str = str(byte_code)[2:-1] 
>> print(byte_code, uc_str)
b'\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \xb7\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Currently I have only two ugly methods,

```
>> uc_str = str(byte_code)[2:-1]
>> uc_str = "".join('\\x{:02x}'.format(c) for c in byte_code)
```

Raw bytes usage:

```
>> my_template = "const char byte_code[] = 'TPL'"
>> uc_str = str(byte_code)[2:-1]
>> my_code = my_template.replace("TPL", uc_str)
# then write my_code to xx.h
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your first method is broken, because any bytes that can be represented as printable ASCII will be, for example:

```
>>> str(b'\x00\x20\x41\x42\x43\x20\x00')[2:-1]
'\\x00 ABC \\x00'
```

The second method is actually okay. Since this feature appears to be missing from stdlib I've published [all-escapes](https://pypi.org/project/all-escapes/) which provides it.

```
pip install all-escapes
```

Example usage:

```
>>> b"\xb7\x00\x00\x00".decode("all-escapes")
'\\xb7\\x00\\x00\\x00'
```

Comment: This is because I want to insert the byte_code to a string template and then write to a .cpp file.

Comment: Then the wording in the question is a little misleading - you don't want to write it directly as *raw bytes*, you want to write a string representation of the bytes.

Comment: Yes. I have modified the description in the question and gave a simple example for why I need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this trying to do something similar with some SNMP code.

```
byte_code = b'\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
text = byte_code.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
writer_func(text)
```

It worked to send an SNMP Hex string as an OctetString when there was no helper support for hex.

See also [standard-encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) and [bytes decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode)

and for anyone looking at the SNMP [Set Types](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmpset)

Answer (score -1):

basic of conversion byte / str  is this :

```
>>> b"abc".decode()
'abc'
>>>
```

or :

```
>>> sb = b"abc"
>>> s = sb.decode()
>>> s
'abc'
>>>
```

The inverse is :

```
>>> "abc".encode()
b'abc'
>>>
```

or :

```
>>> s="abc"
>>> sb=s.encode()
>>> sb
b'abc'
>>>
```

And in your case, you should use errors argument :

```
>>> b"\xb7".decode(errors="replace")
'�'
>>>
```